# Adding ComboBox items

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to shorten this VBA:

```
Me.cboDeptU1.AddItem "1"
Me.cboDeptU1.AddItem "2"
Me.cboDeptU1.AddItem "3"
Me.cboDeptU1.AddItem "4" 
Me.cboDeptU1.AddItem "5"

Me.cboDeptU.SetFocus
```

I also have this one in the same Sub:

```
Me.cboDeptL1.AddItem "1"
Me.cboDeptL1.AddItem "2"
Me.cboDeptL1.AddItem "3"
Me.cboDeptL1.AddItem "4"
Me.cboDeptL1.AddItem "5"

Me.cboDeptL.SetFocus
```

Comment: In addition to the answers you got, you can drop the `Me` specifier, it's implicit/redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
Me.cboDeptU1.AddItem "1"
Me.cboDeptU1.AddItem "2"
Me.cboDeptU1.AddItem "3"
Me.cboDeptU1.AddItem "4" 
Me.cboDeptU1.AddItem "5"
```

With

```
For i = 1 to 5
  Me.cboDeptU1.AddItem Cstr(i)
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you so much. anddddddd  I love you <-- i mean it

Comment: @DavidQuetglas you can click the hollow checkmark underneath to the vote buttons next to this answer, to mark it as *accepted* as a token of your love... or just to get the +2 rep for accepting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you were only adding these items to a completely empty `List`, you could use something like:

```
Me.cboDeptU1.List = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probable your go-to resource.

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut20.htm

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut13a.htm

And...for ListBoxes...

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut11.htm